# Compute Sample Size for Specific Margin of Error & Confidence Level

Tags: sampling, error

I have a population that is in size equals to 65,536. The population follows a **uniform distribution** and is composed of **discrete**, ordered **integer** numbers. From this population I wish to identify the appropriate sample *n* so that it has a specific error of e.g., 5% and a confidence level of 95%.

I have some questions on how I can correctly compute the sample size. The Margin of Error (MOE) formula is:

$\epsilon = z_{\gamma} \times \sqrt{\sigma^2/n}$.

Given that I know the desired error, I can solve for $n$ and identify the sample size. But here I have some questions

(1) $σ^2$:
Since the population follows a discrete uniform distribution, can I compute $σ^2$ as: $(N^2-1)/12 = 357,913,941.25 \text{ for N} = 65,536$ ? [[1]](https://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/pdfd-uniformdisc.htm#:%7E:text=Of%20course%2C%20this%20implies%20that,%E2%88%9AN2%E2%88%92112.)

(2) $z_γ$:
Regarding this value, can I use the the normal distribution table and compute it for $γ = 95$, as shown in [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error)? Or since my population follows discrete uniform distribution I have to do some kind of conversion first? In this case, how can I do it?

(3) Given that (1) and (2) are computed and I can finally solve the error equation for n as:
$e = z_γ \times \sqrt{σ^2/n} \leftrightarrow \\
 n = z_{γ}^{2} \times σ^2/e^2 $

It is of course possible that the sample size will not be  an integer number. In this case I should compute the ceiling of the result, correct? I.e., $\lceil{z_{γ}^{2} \times σ^2/e^2}\rceil$.

Thank you in advance